# Nginx proxy upstream cached?

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

Attempting to resolve an issue that's been annoying me for a bit. I've distilled the symptoms into a set of reproducible steps:

1. I have two sites, `siteA`, and `siteB`. They are both Node.js applications running on different ports (for the sake of example, `4567` and `4568`)
2. Both applications have their own file in `sites_available` (plus a symlink from `sites_enabled`), which contain the directives `proxy_pass http://node_siteA/` and `proxy_pass http://node_siteB/` respectively, inside of a `location` block.
3. They also each have an `upstream` block (defined globally?):

   `upstream node_siteA {               upstream node_siteB {
       server 127.0.0.1:4567;              server 127.0.0.1:4568;
   }                                   }`
4. Site A and Site B have nothing to do with each other.
5. Yes, I am restarting (reloading, actually) nginx every time I make a change.
6. If I take down site B and attempt to access it via the web, I am served site A.

Why is this?

#### Thoughts

- Other times, when I create a new `Site C`, for example, nginx refuses to show me anything except "Welcome to nginx!" for ~5 minutes. This suggests a resolver timeout, perhaps?
- When I access `Site B` after its config has been deleted, and it sends me to `Site A`, this sounds like nginx sending me to servers in a round-robin fashion...

Comment: Show the nginx configuration for each `server`.

Comment: Hi @MichaelHampton, please take a look at [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Z39rCtVb) for `SiteA`. `SiteB`'s config is exactly the same, only with "SiteB" substituted for "SiteA"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012477/proxy-cache-timeout-delay-with-nginx/19778190#19778190). Turns out the problem did not lie with nginx, but with CloudFlare.